# Can I circle around an opponent and avoid opportunity attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, opportunity-attack

I have had trouble finding this information in the PHB.

If as a fighter I stand on one side of an enemy, can I move to the other side of him as long as I stay in reach so that I don't provoke an opportunity attack? (Presumably facing him at all times — like how enemies circle each other in the movies.)

e.g. Me (M) moving around an enemy (E) along the four-space path marked by arrows:

```
 ☐ M ☐          ☐ → ↓
 ☐ E ☐    ——>   ☐ E ↓
 ☐ ☐ ☐          ☐ M ←  

(Start)         (End)
```

Answer (score 39):

**Players Basic Rules, pg 71**

> **Moving Around Other Creatures**
>
> If you leave a hostile creature’s reach during your move,
> you provoke an opportunity attack, as explained later in
> the chapter.

and,

**Players Basic Rules, pg 73**

> **Opportunity Attacks**
>
> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile
> creature that you can see moves out of your reach.

So yes, you can move around the enemy as long as you don't leave the 5ft area around them (5ft is a standard example.  @LegendaryDude pointed out that not all enemies have a 5ft reach.  For combatants with longer reach substitute their reach distance for 5ft and the same principle applies).

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, you can, if you stay within reach

This may be more than the original question is asking but seeing that at least one other question on opportunity attacks is being directed here I think this may be helpful.

#### Attacks of opportunity are only allowed to be taken when an enemy leaves your threat range

PHB 195

> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile creature that you can see moves out of your reach. To make the opportunity attack, you use your reaction to make one melee attack against the provoking creature, the attack occurs right before the creature leaves your reach.

Side-stepping around an enemy will never provoke an opportunity attack from that creature.  Also, when fighting a creature using a Melee weapon with a reach of 10 feet (lances, halberds, etc), or when fighting a creature that naturally has longer reach, a creature stepping back won't proc an opportunity attack until leaving the hostile creature's reach. As a result, when facing an opponent armed with a pole arm, a character can step back without provoking an attack of opportunity as long as they remain within the reach of the weapon.

A character can avoid provoking an opportunity attack through various means.

> You can avoid provoking an opportunity attack by taking the disengage action. You also don't provoke an opportunity attack when you teleport or when someone or something moves you without using your movement, action, or reaction. For example you don't provoke an opportunity attack if an explosion hurls you out of an opponent's reach...

Shoving a creature or using spells like *thunderwave* or *gust of wind* wont allow your allies to make opportunity attacks against the opponent, however if a creature fails checks against *dissonant whispers* or the *fear* spell, their resulting movement can provoke opportunity attacks

How can a character can make an opportunity attack and in what way?  Most commonly feats (if your campaign allows them)

- Polearm Master feat

  > While you are wielding a glaive, halberd, pike, or quarterstaff, other creatures provoke an opportunity attack when they **enter** the reach you have with that weapon.(*emphasis mine.*)
- Sentinel feat

  > When you hit a creature with an opportunity attack its speed becomes 0 for the rest of the turn. Creatures provoke opportunity attacks from you even if they take the disengage action before leaving your reach when a creature within 5 feet of you makes an attack against a target other than you (and that target doesn't have this feat) you can use your reaction to make a melee weapon attack against the attacking creature

The last one is not technically an opportunity attack and does not trigger the other affects of this feat, but I decided to include it for completeness.

- War caster feat

  > When a hostile creature's movement provokes an opportunity from you, you can use your reaction to cast a spell on the creature, rather than making an opportunity attack. The spell must have a casting time of 1 action and must target only that creature.

These should cover the most common situations where opportunity attacks come up. if I missed any go ahead and mention them in the comments.

---

P.S This doesn't count as an opportunity attack but I think it is worth including here for completeness and disambiguation.

- Mage Slayer

> When a creature within 5 feet of you casts a spell you can use your
>   reaction to make a melee attack against that creature.

Comment: Is "threat range" a term of art from earlier editions? If so, I suggest you avoid it and just use the 5e term "reach" in your second header.